# How do I use a URL path instead of a file path in an Open File dialog in Mac OSX or ChromiumOS?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, chromium, google-chrome-os

In Windows 7 (and perhaps earlier), the default "Open File" dialog box allows you to type a full URL into the "File name" section as if it were a file path, e.g. "http://www.example.com/pic.gif" instead of "C:/windows/pictures/pic.gif". When uploading a file to a website on the client side - say, an image - this allows the client to upload a picture located on a server accessible via the URL instead of downloading the image, saving it locally, then referencing the local image in the "Open File" dialog.

It's a great option for Windows users. I have three separate questions:

1. What is this procedure formally called? How do I describe this succinctly so that my searches for more information are fruitful?
2. Can something similar be done in Mac OSX, Chromium OS, or a Linux environment?
3. If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That was called embedding Internet Explorer into Windows, that Microsoft was sued for.

Jokes apart, I would call that "support for generic URL and http: specifically in Open File dialog"

As of Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan, this is not possible, as path is to start with `/`, that is not other protocols supported other then file.

btw, possibly some software could do a hook and add some virtual resource like `/clipboard` or simlink to clipboard content, but I don't know it is possible, or what security risk that would bring.

Looking for answer myself [How to use exact path in Mac OS X open file dialog?](https://superuser.com/questions/1069218/how-to-use-exact-path-in-mac-os-x-open-file-dialog)